# dynamic allocating array of arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, allocation

I don't truly understand some basic things in C like dynamically allocating array of arrays.
I know you can do:

```
int **m;
```

in order to declare a 2 dimensional array (which subsequently would be allocated using some *alloc function). Also it can be "easily" accessed by doing `*(*(m + line) + column)`. But how should I assign a value to an element from that array? Using gcc the following statement `m[line][column] = 12;` fails with a segmentation fault.

Any article/docs will be appreciated. :-)

Comment: This is no "array of arrays".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `m[line][column] = 12` syntax is ok (provided `line` and `column` are in range).

However, you didn't write the code you use to allocate it, so it's hard to get whether it is wrong or right. It should be something along the lines of

```
m = (int**)malloc(nlines * sizeof(int*));

for(i = 0; i < nlines; i++)
  m[i] = (int*)malloc(ncolumns * sizeof(int));
```

Some side-notes:

- This way, you can allocate each line with a different length (eg. a triangular array)
- You can realloc() or free() an individual line later while using the array
- You must free() every line, when you free() the entire array

Comment: @jpalecek: The way I allocated memory for that was: m = malloc(lines * columns * sizeof(int *));

Comment: @hyperboreean: That would allocate a one dimensional array of pointers. What you want is an array of pointers that each point to another array. You need to first allocate the array of pointers, then allocate memory for each array that is being pointed to.

Comment: Wow, two pathetically useless edits.  @chakrit: casting malloc is generally considered bad practice in C as it is not necessary and can mask errors.  +1 for the original answer.

Comment: @Robert, it unfortunately depends on the compiler implementation.  Some older compilers have non-standard mallocs that require a cast.  VisualStudio was this way until fairly recently (can't remember the exact version)

Comment: @JaredPar: Any standard-conforming compiler will not require you to cast the return value of malloc.  I find it difficult to believe that Visual Studio ever required this for C code (you aren't confusing C with C++ are you?).

Comment: Casting is good practice when it eliminates a warning and shows intent.  Some of us use older compilers.  I use MSVC 6, and that case is always in order.

Comment: Casting malloc is good practice in C++ because it is required if the variable on the LHS is not a void pointer.  It is bad practice in C because the warnings it eliminates are almost always errors that need to be properly addressed and removing the warning just treats the symptom.

Comment: @EvilTeach: Regarding MSVC 6, can you compile a simple example that doesn't cast malloc and compile it as *C*, not C++, code and provide the error message you get?  You will get an error if you compile it as C++ (since it forbids the implicit conversion) but you should be fine compiling it as C.

Comment: Regarding older compilers: The only compilers that wouldn't allow this are those that prior to C89.  Void pointers were introduced in C89 and implicit conversion to/from void * was introduced at the same time so the idea that a malloc that returns void * that needs to be cast doesn't hold water.

Comment: @Robert: Search on Google Code: `=\s*malloc\b lang:c` -- 386,000 vs. `=\s*\([^)]+\)\s*malloc\b lang:c` -- 395,000 Conclusion: both practice are common.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: It is also common practice to not check buffer sizes when using strcat/strcpy/etc.  *Common Practice* != *Good Practice*.

Answer (score 5):

Your syntax m[line][colummn] is correct.  But in order to use a 2D array in C, you must allocate memory for it.  For instance this code will allocated memory for a table of given line and column.

```
int** AllocateArray(int line, int column) {
  int** pArray = (int**)malloc(line*sizeof(int*));
  for ( int i = 0; i < line; i++ ) {
    pArray[i] = (int*)malloc(column*sizeof(int));
  }
  return pArray;
}
```

Note, I left out the error checks for malloc for brevity.  A real solution should include them.

Comment: There are several ways to dynamically create "multidimensional arrays" in C with subtle but important differences, see http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html for details.  Also, as a warning to others regarding the dangers of casting malloc: http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a 2d array - it's an array of arrays - thus it needs the multiple allocations.

Comment: Probably this was my problem that I was getting a seg fault.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a modified version of [quinmars' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455960/dynamic-allocating-array-of-arrays-in-c#456090) which only allocates a single block of memory and can be used with generic values by courtesy of `void *`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

void ** array2d(size_t rows, size_t cols, size_t value_size)
{
    size_t index_size = sizeof(void *) * rows;
    size_t store_size = value_size * rows * cols;

    char * a = malloc(index_size + store_size);
    if(!a) return NULL;

    memset(a + index_size, 0, store_size);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        ((void **)a)[i] = a + index_size + i * cols * value_size;

    return (void **)a;
}

int printf(const char *, ...);

int main()
{
    int ** a = (int **)array2d(5, 5, sizeof(int));
    assert(a);
    a[4][3] = 42;
    printf("%i\n", a[4][3]);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if it's really safe to cast `void **` to `int **` (I think the standard allows for conversions to take place when converting to/from `void *` ?), but it works in gcc. To be on the safe side, you should replace every occurence of `void *` with `int *` ...

---

The following macros implement a type-safe version of the previous algorithm:

```
#define alloc_array2d(TYPE, ROWS, COLS) \
    calloc(sizeof(TYPE *) * ROWS + sizeof(TYPE) * ROWS * COLS, 1)

#define init_array2d(ARRAY, TYPE, ROWS, COLS) \
    do { for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i) \
        ARRAY[i] = (TYPE *)(((char *)ARRAY) + sizeof(TYPE *) * ROWS + \
        i * COLS * sizeof(TYPE)); } while(0)
```

Use them like this:

```
int ** a = alloc_array2d(int, 5, 5);
init_array2d(a, int, 5, 5);
a[4][3] = 42;
```

Comment: `calloc` allocates and *zeroes* the array. `init_array2d` is probably redundant, unless there is a version which might set each cell to a given value that is not `(TYPE)0`

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with the other answers, it is in most cases better to allocate the whole array at once, because malloc is pretty slow.

```
int **
array_new(size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
    int **array2d, **end, **cur;
    int *array;

    cur = array2d = malloc(rows * sizeof(int *));
    if (!array2d)
        return NULL;

    array = malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(int));
    if (!array)
    {
        free(array2d);
        return NULL;
    }

    end = array2d + rows;
    while (cur != end)
    {
        *cur = array;
        array += cols;
        cur++;
    }

    return array2d;
}
```

To free the array simply do:
 `free(*array); free(array);`

Note: this solution only works if you don't want to change the order of the rows, because you could then lose the address of the first element, which you need to free the array later.

Comment: That's a witty solution :) Although if I wanted to allocate it at once, I would probably resort to the "array[i*cols+j]" addressing and ditch the "array2d" array.

Answer (score 1):

Humm.  How about old fashion smoke and mirrors as an option?

```
#define ROWS  5
#define COLS 13
#define X(R, C) *(p + ((R) * ROWS) + (C))

int main(void)
{
    int *p = (int *) malloc (ROWS * COLS * sizeof(int));
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        size_t r;
        size_t c;
        for (r = 0; r < ROWS; r++)
        {
            for (c = 0; c < COLS; c++)
            {
                 X(r,c) = r * c;  /* put some silly value in that position */ 
            }
        }

        /* Then show the contents of the array */ 
        for (r = 0; r < ROWS; r++)
        {
            printf("%d ", r);   /* Show the row number */ 

            for (c = 0; c < COLS; c++)
            {
                 printf("%d", X(r,c));
            }

            printf("\n");
        }

        free(p);
    }
    else
    {
        /* issue some silly error message */ 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `malloc(3)` for allocate the first array and putting in there pointers created by `malloc(3)` should work with `array[r][c]` because it should be equivalent to `*(*(array + r) + c)`, it is in the C standard.