# C: Dynamic array of pointers to array of structure

Tags: c

I have a structure and a bidimensional array of those structs:

```
typedef struct {
char exit_n;
char exit_s;
char exit_w;
char exit_e;
} room;

room map[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT];
```

I need an array of pointers those structs. The following code compiles, but I don't get the wanted result. Any help? This is getting really confused to me, any explanation would be appreciated

```
room *rooms;
rooms = (room*)malloc(sizeof(room*) * ROOM_NUM);
[..]
rooms[n] = map[room_x][room_y];
[..]
```

Answer (score 9):

Actually, I think you want

```
room** rooms;
rooms = (room**)malloc(sizeof(room*) * ROOM_NUM);
[..]
rooms[n] = &map[room_x][room_y];
```

This gives you an array of pointers to your rooms.

Answer (score 1):

I'm am pretty sure you want

```
sizeof(room)
```

You need to allocate enough space for the struct.  You are only allocating for a pointer.

You also may need to allocate differently if you want a 2D array:
see here [[dynamic allocating array of arrays in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455960/dynamic-allocating-array-of-arrays-in-c)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455960/dynamic-allocating-array-of-arrays-in-c)

Comment: Incidentally, in this particular case sizeof(room)==sizeof(room*) on a 32 bit system :D

Answer (score 1):

The major issue I see is that you are using `sizeof(room*)`. This means that you are taking the size of a pointer to a structure, which is not what you want. You want to allocate the size of the structure, so make that `sizeof(room)`. Also, use `calloc` in this case, not `malloc`, as you are basically implementing the former's functionality by multiplying the number of rooms by the size of the room.

Comment: isn't this like making another array of _rooms_ where i want an array of _pointers to room_?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Some of the other posts have done it right.

Answer (score 1):

In your current code, `rooms` becomes an array of `room` structures, not an array of pointers. If you want an array of pointers that each point to your `map` array, you need another layer of indirection:

```
room** rooms = malloc(ROOM_NUM * sizeof *rooms);
// ...
rooms[n] = &map[room_x][room_y];
```

(Or you can use `sizeof (room *)` like your code has instead of `sizeof *rooms`; I prefer to write it that way to avoid duplicating type information.)

Comment: It seems to me that `rooms` is supposed to be an alternative, 1-dimensional way of accessing `map` instead of being 2-dimensional.

Comment: I don't think so. He's got ROOM_NUM rooms. I'm guessing ROOM_NUM is equal to the product of the map's dimensions. room*** wouldn't work for a 2D array anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate space for the pointers *and for the rooms* and then initialize the pointers to point to the rooms.

```
room *rooms; 
room **prooms;
rooms = (room*)malloc((sizeof(room) + sizeof(room*)) * ROOM_NUM); 
prooms = (room**)(&rooms[ROOM_NUM]);
for (int ii = 0; ii < ROOM_NUM; ++ii)
   prooms[ii] = &rooms[ii];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want an array of pointers to all the `room` values in `map`.  Since there are `MAP_WIDTH*MAP_HEIGHT` such values, we need that many pointers:

```
room *rooms[MAP_WIDTH*MAP_HEIGHT];
```

The above declares `rooms` as an array of pointers.

Now, to assign the values:

```
size_t i;
size_t j;

for (i=0; i < MAP_WIDTH; ++i)
    for (j=0; j < MAP_HEIGHT; ++j)
        rooms[i*MAP_HEIGHT+j] = &map[i][j];
```

We basically find the address of each element in `map`, and store it in the correct entry in `rooms`.

Is this what you wanted?